# How to ignore aws_iam_policy changing when upgrade version with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

When I upgrade `aws provider` version from 3.22.0 to 3.28.0, it will change some `aws_iam_policy`

```
# module.aws_config_role.aws_iam_policy.default will be updated in-place
~ resource "aws_iam_policy" "default" {
        path   = "/"
      ~ policy = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                  ~ {
```

Is there a way to ignore it? I didn't find a `lifecycle ignore` feature on the [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably, want to keep your policy up-to-date with your terraform configuration. But if you want to ignore policy changes, the following should do the job:

```
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [policy]
}
```

Comment: If it's in `data "aws_iam_policy_document" "aws_config_role_policy" {`, `source_json = data.aws_iam_policy.config_role.policy`, how to ignore?